# I am using fabric.js and I have some problems with Text fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, fabricjs

```
$scope.addText=function(){
                var itext = new fabric.IText( "New Text" ,defualtText );
                itext.set({
                  'left' : canvas.width/2,
                  'top' : canvas.height/2,
                  'originX':'center',
                  'originY':'center'
                });


                itext.setControlsVisibility({
                    mt: false, 
                    mb: false, 
                    ml: false, 
                    mr: false, 
                });

                 canvas.add(itext);
                 itext.center();
                 canvas.renderAll();
                 itext.hiddenTextarea.focus();
                 itext.setCoords(); 
                 canvas.setActiveObject(itext);




            };
```

I am using fabric.js and I have some problems with Text fields. They are apparently not editable on Android devices. I can select the Text area, but I cannot edit it. (In fact Mobile keypad dosent open).

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: "version": "1.7.20",

Comment: Keypad is opening in mobile(Android), Here is [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/durga598/zqeu83kL/15/)

Comment: Your code is working correctly , where were i went wrong then ? can u help please ?

Comment: `var itext = new fabric.IText("New Text", defualtText);` What is `defualtText` here?

Comment: itext.setControlsVisibility({
                        mt: false, 
                        mb: false, 
                        ml: false, 
                        mr: false, 
                    });
Is There any issue with this code

Comment: var itext = new fabric.IText( "New Text" ,defualtText ); same as it is like yours

Comment: make a fiddle / snippet here , stating your problem

Comment: @Durga : I have change code example again please check in code and let me know if i have gone wrong ... please help  got stuck from last 2 days

Comment: That code u state below,  will solve the text keypad problem in mobile ?

Comment: Remove defualtText as I am not sure what you are adding in there, and you are using itext.center() which will make it to center of canvas, so you no need to set left and top for itext. Except that I didnt find any error.

Comment: @Durga : its not working , i followed ua steps but still its not working

Comment: @Durga: its working on Iphone but not in android